# Interprocess communication in F#

Tags: .net, f#, parallel-processing, dsl

I'm working on an external DSL in F#. The language must allow parallel loops:

```
start 5 times
    operation
```

This starts `operation` asynchronously 5 times and continues with the execution. However, things are a bit complicated because `operation` uses a Thread-unsafe library (no way to avoid this), thus I suppose each iteration must be started in a separate process.

Assuming this is the only way around the thread-unsafety problem, How can I start a process and pass the execution subtree (a distriminated union at this point) that must be executed?

I'm thinking WCF named pipes, but would like to hear if there are alternatives (WCF means starting the process, waiting for a call-back (keeping track of it) and returning the subtree -not very functonal-friendly code but maybe I'm wrong).

Also, performance is not really important in this case.

**EDIT:**
Turns out I don't need any communication after the process has started. I'm tempted to simply pass the expression string as a process startup parameter and let him parse/execute it. I'm still interested in alternatives, but I suppose it doesn't get any simpler than that.

Comment: Can you use synchronization primitives (`ManualResetEvent`, `Semaphore`, etc) to achieve thread safety? That seems much simpler than IPC.

Comment: No, in the sense that the library is huge and I'm not allowed to make any change to it, plus every call must truly run concurrently.

Comment: Would it suffice to use multiple AppDomains?

Comment: This MSDN page has a WCF named pipes example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx

Comment: If your work and results can be serialized, [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) are another option.

Comment: @Daniel AppDomains should do the trick and looks like the best option here. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running each operation in a separate AppDomain--if possible--would be simpler than IPC.